# OCI KBHS-00719: Error 'unknown'; Archived object is not restored

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, cloud

I am encountering below error message from RMAN backup to OCI.

> Either the bucket named 'DB_BACKUP' does not exist in the namespace
>   'UNIcredits' or you are not authorized to access it. KBHS-01404: See
>   trace file
>   D:\APP\ORAADMIN\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\RDBMS\TRACE\sbtio_11000_11672.log
>   for details KBHS-00719: Error 'unknown'; Archived object is not
>   restored. KBHS-00700: HTTP response error 'Conflict'

RMAN backups are successful and have been validated and existing in the said bucket, the error is encountered on the crosscheck from sbt_tape. I have two changes done before the error has been encountered. I changed the policy setting in the bucket to archive files from the standard 30 days to 7 days and delete policy from 90 days to 10 days, it deleted most of my backup in cloud older than 10 days. I also changed my account password in OCI.

Oracle support advise to ignore it since backups are successful but its bugging me as per my housekeeping script shows its completed with errors.

Below is the script for RMAN backup

```
run {  
allocate channel CHAN_FUL device type sbt PARMS='SBT_LIBRARY=D:\app\Oraadmin\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\opc\bdohi\lib\oraopc.dll, SBT_PARMS=(OPC_PFILE=D:\app\Oraadmin\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\opc\bdohi\bdohi_config.ora)';
configure retention policy to recovery window of 7 days;
configure controlfile autobackup on;
configure default device type to sbt_tape;
backup incremental level 0 section size 2G database ;
sql 'alter system archive log current';  
backup archivelog all delete input;
}  
delete noprompt expired backup;
list backup summary; 
crosscheck backup;
exit;
```